# is it possible to interact or avoid ChromeDriver (Webdriver) save password alert?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

is it possible to interact with save password alert in ChromeDriver? or just to configure chromedriver such that it doesn't appear.

I have tried following things however it's not working.

```
ChromeOptions Options = new ChromeOptions(); 
Options.AddArgument("--enable-save-password-bubble=true");  
IWebDriver.driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Comment: please share your code what you have tried

Comment: I think this is the issue with c#. you can refer [.NET ChromeOptions: No way to add experimental ChromeOptions](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6632)

Comment: I tried these codes:  `ChromeOptions Options = new ChromeOptions();
           Options.AddArgument("--enable-save-password-bubble=true");`
and:
`IWebDriver.driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();`

and also other codes but they don't work

Comment: Do you want to save the password or avoid the alert?

Comment: I think saving password will be easier but it will be great if you have solutions for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--enable-save-password-bubble=true` is [deprecated](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1015#c28) from what I've seen.  I've done a lot of searching on this recently and this is [the fix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1015#c31) that worked for me.  Note that `false` should **not** be surrounded by quotes.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
```